# Algorithm for 1-1 matching of values from different lists based on match score

Tags: algorithm

I have two lists, listA and listB, probably of different lengths. I want to match objects from listA one to one with objects from listB, for the best possible matches.

I have an algorithm that can give a matching score for any pair of objects. What I need is an efficient (and reasonably easy to read) algorithm for getting the highest scoring matches together 1-1. There will only ever be one exact match per object in listA, but there may be possible matches with the same object that have the same score, and in that case it doesn't matter which is matched. It also doesn't matter if some objects are left in either or both of the lists at the end because of the matching scores not being high enough.

The algorithm that I have come up with may have some flaws that I haven't spotted, and there may be a standard way of doing this that I haven't been able to find, so I'm looking for suggestions/corrections.

Here's my attempt:

```
for (a in listA)
    for (b in listB)
        if (!b.hasPerfectMatch)
            var score = calculateMatchScore(a,b)
            if (score > b.score)    //better match than any previous
                remove any previous match to b
                add previous match a to end of listA
                b.score = score
                if (b.hasPerfectMatch)
                    break    //found exact match for this a
```

(I will be using Java by the way)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're describing a classic problem called maximum-weight bipartite matching and there are many excellent algorithms already around that solve it. I'd recommend reading up on the Hungarian algorithm as a starting point, since it's simple, fast, and has the guarantee that it's already known to produce optimal answers.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks. A difficult thing to find when you don't know the name of the problem you're trying to solve!